# Why did Munkres write "a smallest element" instead of "the smallest element" in this sentence?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I am very poor at English but I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

On p.85, Example 3:

> The positive integers $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ form an ordered set with a smallest element.

Why did Munkres write "a smallest element" instead of "the smallest element" in this sentence?

Comment: In English, *the* is a definite article and refers to a specific one (e.g.. that has already been mentioned)

Comment: A smallest element is certainly unique, so after establishing its existence you can go on and talk about "the smallest element". But the sentence "the positive integers form an ordered set with the smallest element" sounds strange. It makes it sound like there is something out there which you're calling "the smallest element", and that this set just happens to contain that thing that you're referring to.

Comment: Another way to think about it is in answer to a question: "Does the set have a smallest element?"

Comment: This is not about mathematics! It belongs on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @EthanDlugie Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Théophile Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Théophile Thank you very much for your example. If I read "Does the set $A$ have the smallest element?", I think $A$ contains the smallest element of some set $B$. Thank you.

Comment: "Does the set have the smallest element?" is not correct. But I guess "Does the set have the smallest element in it?" is correct. Am I correct?

Comment: @tchappyha I am glad to help. The word "the" needs context. You cannot say "Does the set have the smallest element," unless you are referring to some smallest element that you previously described. Similarly, "Do you have a favourite colour?", not "Do you have the favourite colour?" This is hard to explain in a comment; as TonyK suggested, you could try English Language Learners for a more detailed explanation. Good luck!

Comment: @Théophile Thank you very much!